# Eloquent where owner equals follow

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a twitter like feed in an application, I have a database called `connections` where inside there's `user` and `follow` and another database called `feed` containing `owner` which would equal to the `follow` column in `connections`.

What I could do if had every id of a follower statically is to use `where('owner', '=' $follow)` on each follower and return it.

I tried this approach but it wasn't ideal:

```
Get each follower inside connections;

foreach(follower) {

Get 10 of the latest posts orderBy "created_at";

Push into array;

}

shuffle array;

limit array to 15;

return array;
```

That also ended with the returned array not being ordered by created date.

How would I use eloquent to get the feed item only if the user follows the owner in the best/simplest way?

Are there any specific Laravel tools that can be used?

**Also the database layout isn't fixed as it is, it can be altered if needed to better suite this.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a many-to-many relationship between the user and itself.  See the laravel eloquent documentation http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships.  I didn't test this code but it should be enough to get you started down the right track.

Create a pivot table called "user_following" with:

(int) id, (int) user_id, (int) following_id

Then do something like this:

```
<?php

// Model 

class User extends Eloquent {

    public function following()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_following', 'user_id', 'following_id');
    }

    public function tweets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Tweet')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

}



// controller

$tweetsOfWhoImFollowing = User::find($id)->following->tweets;
```